# how to solve this problem with render in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I transferred my project from just React to the React, Redux and react-redux stack and an error occurred.
Before transferring to this stack, everything worked adequately.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHt0B.png). I tried to fix it in 3 days, but it didn’t work out.

My index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import store from "./store/date";
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";
const rerender=()=> {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Provider store={store}>
            <App /></Provider></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById("root")
    );
};
rerender();
store.subscribe(()=>{
    rerender()
})
```

My file with date (date.js):

```
import {combineReducers, createStore} from "redux";
import realtorsDate from "./realtorsDate";
let isMenuVisible = true;
const UpdateMenu = (state = isMenuVisible, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UpdateMenu' :
            let copystate = !state;
            return copystate;
        default :
            return state;
     }
};
let menuDate=[
    {
        Name: "Main",
        Symbol: "/",
        Src: ""
    },
    {
        Name: "logo",
        Symbol: "img",
        Src: "./../Images/logo.png"
    },
    {
        Name: "About us",
        Symbol: "#",
        Src: "about"
    },
    {
        Name: "Our team",
        Symbol: "#",
        Src: "team"
    },
    {
        Name: "Vacancies",
        Symbol: "/",
        Src: "work"
    },
    {
        Name: "Advantage",
        Symbol: "#",
        Src: "adv"
    },
    {
        Name: "Contacts",
        Symbol: "#",
        Src: "cont"
    }
]
let reducers=combineReducers({UpdateMenu,realtorsDate})
const store=createStore (UpdateMenu,menuDate);
export default store;
```

Container component:

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import MobileMenu from "./menu";
let menuStateText= {
    type: "UpdateMenu"
}
let MapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return {
        menuDate: state.menuDate}}
let MapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
    return {
        UpdateMenu: ()=> {
            dispatch (menuStateText)
        }
    }
}
let MobileMenuContainer=connect(MapDispatchToProps,MapStateToProps)(MobileMenu);
export default MobileMenuContainer
```

Component:

```
import React from "react"
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faBars} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faBars";
import "./../css/App.css"
import ParagraphOfMenu from "./paragraphMenu";
class MobileMenu extends React.Component {
    render(props) {
        debugger
        let Menu =()=>{this.props.menuDate.map((el,i) => (
            <ParagraphOfMenu el={el} key={i}/>
        ))}
        return (
            <div className="mobileMenuBlock">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} onClick="return false"></FontAwesomeIcon>
                <header className={(this.props.UpdateMenu) ?"hidemenu":"mobilemenu"}>
                    <nav>
                        <ul className="">
                            <Menu></Menu>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default MobileMenu
```

link to code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-lovelace-weh66?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

thanks in advance

Comment: DId you check if you are receiving menuData in props of MobileMenu?

Comment: @VaibhavSingh yep,undefind

Comment: @VaibhavSingh but i don't know what i did wrong

Comment: Can you create a codesanbox with your code and share it here?

Comment: @ArpithaChandrashekara https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-lovelace-weh66?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a lot of mistakes in the code:

1. `connect` takes first argument as MapStateToProps and second as MapDispatchToProps, you are passing it in an incorrect order.
2. your variable `let Menu` is defined as a function it should be a Component.
3. The `Update` method is defined in render method it should instead be defined as a class method. Since you are already and call the method you receive in props there.

You can refer this working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-bose-5lejz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

```js
let MobileMenuContainer = connect(
  MapStateToProps,
  MapDispatchToProps
)(MobileMenu);
```

Here is your problem, you need to pass `MapStateToProps` instead of `MapDispatchToProps`

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of issues in this code, so I'll point them out to you and hope they can help you.

First of all, take a look at this:

```
const store = createStore(UpdateMenu, menuDate);
```

What this does is to **create a new store and initialize it with the value you passed as an argument**. Since you passed a single reducer to the `createStore` function, the value assigned to the `state` will be the array you had in your `menuDate` variable.

Right now **you cannot access `state.menuDate` because `state` it's not an object**: it contains the array itself. If you want to get that array, you'll have to update `MapStateToProps` method like this:

```
let MapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { menuDate: state }
}
```

I've also noticed that **you use `combineReducers`, but you end up not using the combined reducer** for anything.

```
let reducers = combineReducers({
  UpdateMenu,
  realtorsDate
});
```

If you want to use both, you should update the call to `createStore` by passing it the combined reducers rather than `UpdateMenu`.

```
createStore(reducers)
```

If you choose to do so, keep in mind that the store you create will have the following structure:

```
{
  UpdateMenu: [value returned by the UpdateMenu reducer],
  realtorsDate: [value returned by the realtorsDate reducer]
}
```

If you want to apply a different structure for your store, you must change the object you pass to `combineReducer`. Here's an example:

```
combineReducers({
  post: postReducer,
  topic: topicReducer
})
```

You should also take a look at how you're calling `connect`:

```
let MobileMenuContainer=connect(MapDispatchToProps,MapStateToProps)(MobileMenu);
```

**You're passing the two arguments in the opposite order**. As you can see in the [official `react-redux` docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect), `MapStateToProps` should be the first param, and `MapDispatchToProps` the second one.

The last, and not least, issue that I found lies in the implementation of the `UpdateMenu` reducer itself.

```
const UpdateMenu = (state = isMenuVisible, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UpdateMenu' :
            let copystate = !state;
            return copystate;
        default :
            return state;
     }
};
```

I'm not really sure about what your action is meant to do, but **right now your state contains an array of items**. **When the action `UpdateMenu` triggers**, though, **that array is replaced by a `false` value**. This means you're losing all of your data, so you should probably review this.

If you don't prevent this from happening, you'll come accross a new error when calling `map` because your state does no longer contain an array after the `UpdateMenu` action has been dispatched. The reducer should return a new array with the updated data so everything works as expected.